# Configuring compiz from the cli

Tags: command-line, compiz, gconf

At work we're using 11.10 but for some reason IT refuse to install CCSM or gconf-editor.

I know I can edit the config using gconftool-2, but does anyone know of a comprehensive list of the available options?

The things I'm mainly looking for are the option to turn off the unity bar autohide and to turn on window snapping (ie windows snapping to other windows).

Cheers.

Comment: Do you have proper file tree branching (with %gconf.xml) in `~/.gconf/apps/compizconfig-1`

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1925463   try that one

Comment: @zetah I believe so - there is a directory structure, and I've already managed to use the link provided by raja.genupula to turn off auto-hide of the unity bar (thanks btw). I really just need a link to a list of the possible options.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change snap settings in CCSM so that appropriate file was created...

Here is contents of `~/.gconf/apps/compiz-1/plugins/snap/screen0/options/%gconf.xml` with snapping set to windows edges instead screen edges:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gconf>
    <entry name="edges_categories" mtime="1337013971" type="list" ltype="int">
        <li type="int" value="1"/>
    </entry>
</gconf>
```

I hope that's the file